# fitting for random remnants of known perturbers

Tags: modeling, fitting

I have the following problem:

We try to analysis spectra. In our data analysis, we have to correct for perturbers that occur always at the same frequency and can be approximated by a Gaussian of roughly constant width. 
In the processing, we subtract the mean of these "lines". This works quite well, however, we suspect that the line strength of the perturbers varies strongly throughout the measurement - thus subtracting the average leaves artefacts of these lines (which we observe in the spectra!). Given that we have a very strong prior to the position and the width of these perturbing lines I am trying to include these perturbations in our model fitting process (we fit a template spectra to the observed spectra).

Expliclty, my current approach would be the following:
$max Likelihood = 0.5 ln  \sum [(Data - Model - Model.of.differences)^2/errors^2]$

Given that "fitting for random remnants of known perturbers" seems like a quite common problem I wonder if there are some standard recipes for such an approach? However, my google didn't churn out as much as I hoped

Comment: If you know the Gaussian peak's position along with the width, you can determine the amplitude of a Gaussian peak from the Gaussian peak equation - and then try subtracting those?

Comment: Hm yes - but what remains after the reduction of the data is essentially the difference between the  real& noisy spectrum and the perturbing lines (which are the Gaussians).  So, of course, we could just subtract Gaussians at the expected positions - but thats quite crude. But if there is no better more advanced procedure that's what I'll have to do I guess.